# Why my app always showing greeting preview instead of the work (design) that i have done on it?

Tags: java

I am new to Andriod development, I just started my first course on it. My problem is that i just made the simple learning app taught by the instructor ,the app is still showing the "Hello " instead of the work that I have done on it ,i want that work to be displayed on screen when I Run app on Emulator...so  can someone answer ??

I try to search this,rest the activity.XML  but the same thing happening again and again

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just build new project in **Empty Views Activity** instead of **Empty Activity**

you will see old theme.